# How to unload css when changing route using webpack?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, webpack, webpack-style-loader

With [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) changing route unloads the current state's css (using [angular-css](https://github.com/castillo-io/angular-css)).

However when the css is packed using [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) the state's css does not unload.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the `persist: false` option? But I think it's the default.

Comment: @EmileBergeron it did not work.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that since it's the default, you must've tried it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found a workaround but we would prefer a real fix.

We combined [useable styles](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader#reference-counted-api) and two undocumented broadcasts in [angular-css](https://github.com/castillo-io/angular-css) ([$cssAdd](https://github.com/castillo-io/angular-css/blob/master/angular-css.js#L512) and [$cssRemove](https://github.com/castillo-io/angular-css/blob/master/angular-css.js#L545))

The code looks like this:

```
  $rootScope.$on('$cssAdd', function (event, stylesheets) {
    angular.forEach( stylesheets, function(stylesheet){
      if (stylesheet.use)
        stylesheet.use();
    });
  });
  $rootScope.$on('$cssRemove', function (event, stylesheets) {
    angular.forEach( stylesheets, function(stylesheet){
      if (stylesheet.unuse)
        stylesheet.unuse();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Very elegant solution.